# Java Springboot WebClient call to API results in http-415

Tags: java, spring-boot, paypal, webclient

I am working with Java Spring boot - and I am trying to complete the integration of the paypal subscriptions api.

I've got a show subscription plan working in WebClient - although I am unable to complete the functionality for the cancel subscription method.

I get a 415 error --

"message": "415 Unsupported Media Type from POST [https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-JJ0B8HRKSRYV/cancel"](https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-JJ0B8HRKSRYV/cancel%22),

https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/responses/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_cancel
-- when I look at the curl approach - it claims content-type and accept are in the header -- but it could also be the way I've tried to add the body?

https://reflectoring.io/spring-webclient/

//showSubscriptionDetails method

```
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/api/showsubscriptiondetails")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> showSubscriptionDetails(
        @RequestParam("subscriptionID") String subscriptionID
) throws PayPalRESTException {
    BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();

    String bearerToken = generateAccessToken();
    String token = bearerToken.split(" ")[1].trim();

    WebClient client = WebClient.create(host);

    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = client.get()
            .uri("/v1/billing/subscriptions/"+subscriptionID+"?fields=plan")
            .headers(h -> {
                h.setBearerAuth(token);
            })
            .retrieve();

    String responseBody = responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class).block();


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode root = null;
    try {
        root = mapper.readTree(responseBody);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonNode status = root.path("status");
    JsonNode plan = root.path("plan").get("name");

    BasicDBObject res = new BasicDBObject();
    res.put("status", status);
    res.put("plan", plan);

    response.setCode("OK");
    response.setData(res);
    response.setDescription(appMessageLocalUtil.getLanguageMessage("subscription.found"));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
}
```

//cancelSubscription method

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> bodyValues = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
bodyValues.add("reason", "too expensive");


String bearerToken = generateAccessToken();
String token = bearerToken.split(" ")[1].trim();

WebClient client = WebClient.create(host);

WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = client.post()
        .uri("/v1/billing/subscriptions/"+subscriptionID+"/cancel")
        .headers(h -> {
            h.setBearerAuth(token);
        })
        .retrieve();

String responseBody = responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class).block();

System.out.println("responseSpec-- "+ responseSpec);
System.out.println("responseBody-- "+ responseBody);
```

... attempts

I've tried adding the content type in the header and as part of the main build but nothing seems to pass.

```
       WebClient client = WebClient.create(host);

        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = client.post()
                .uri("/v1/billing/subscriptions/"+subscriptionID+"/cancel")
                .headers(h -> {
                    h.setBearerAuth(token);
                    //h.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
                    //h.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                })
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                //.defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
                //.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                //.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(bodyValues))
                .retrieve();
```

### --
21st April 2023

working code was this - making body an object and using fromValue in the bodyinserter -- responseBody is null on outcome- but it does cancel the subscribe id

```
BasicDBObject body = new BasicDBObject();
body.put("reason", "xxx");

String bearerToken = generateAccessToken();
String token = bearerToken.split(" ")[1].trim();

WebClient client = WebClient.create(host);

WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = client.post()
        .uri("/v1/billing/subscriptions/"+subscriptionID+"/cancel")
        .headers(h -> {
            h.setBearerAuth(token);
        })
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(body))
        .retrieve();

String responseBody = responseSpec.bodyToMono(String.class).block();
System.out.println("responseSpec-- "+ responseSpec);
System.out.println("responseBody-- "+ responseBody);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api doc you link to says the cancel body is json and contains {“reason”: “too expensive”}. You are sending a form. Hence 415: form ≠ json.

Try this:

```
String body = “{\”reason\”: \”too expensive\”}”;

WebClient client = WebClient.create(host);

        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = client.post()
   .uri("/v1/billing/subscriptions/"+subscriptionID+"/cancel")
            .headers(h -> {
                h.setBearerAuth(token);
            })
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(body))
            .retrieve();
```

Comment: this returns a 400 error --  400 Bad Request from POST

Comment: No more 415 so I have answered your question. Maybe the subscription Id is wonky?? Add some code to get the body of the 400 response, print it out and add it to a new question.

Comment: I got it working if I changed the body to an object -- BasicDBObject body = new BasicDBObject();
        body.put("reason", "xxx");

Comment: .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Comment: I have edited my answer to also fix the 400.

Comment: String body = “{\”reason\”: \”too expensive\”}”; -- this works - but it does seem a messy way of making the object

Comment: Agree, irl I would define a class with a field “reason” and post that but this format doesn’t really facilitate. My focus is on the original question, ie resolving the 415 (and then the 400.

Comment: Are you able to share documentation that led you to this solution -- I've not found many examples.

Comment: I have lots of experience - seen many 415s and they are invariably because a form was submitted but json expected or viceversa. The api doc was pretty clear about the content-type, I missed the structure of the post payload, mostly because it’s a bit silly - a class with a single field. The single field could be posted. Googling “what causes an http 415 response” would get you pretty close

Comment: What I mean is - the examples I found indicated the body should be a MultiValueMap and wrapped in a fromFormData - I couldn't see a clear example that proposed just a fromValue.

Comment: MultiValueMap/fromFormData is for a backend accepting submissions from html forms. An API is far more likely to accept json. Some example implantations - https://codersee.com/spring-5-webclient-with-spring-boot/ and this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62073018/spring-webclient-post-method-body.